# Сигнальный сервер для видео конференций на socket.io

Tags: java, socket.io, jetty

Я хочу реализовать видео конференции по этому примеру: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/video-conferencing

Используется Jetty сервлет контейнер. Вопрос в том, как связать Jetty сервер и socket.io клиент?